# How can a given conv neural net layer handle filters of different size?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, filter

traditional method is to use multiple filters of same dimensions but with different weights and stack the output (basically concatenate them) that is then to be fed into the next conv layer.

If I want to deal with multiple filters of different dimensions (i.e. filters with smaller dimensions are optimal for smaller feature while filters with bigger dimensions are optimal for big sized feature)

then how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

One version of what you described is called Inception layer, outlined in [Going Deeper with Convolutions](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43022.pdf) paper.

Other than that, if you want to concatenate conv layers with different receptive fields, but still want their dimensions to match, you might try to use strided convolutions with different striding. For a nice illustration of strided convolution see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360899/difference-between-strided-and-non-strided-convolution).

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it. There's nothing that prevents you from having filters of different sizes in the same convolutional layer. You can still convolve by each filter as usual and concatenate the outputs as you've described.

From a practical implementation perspective, I would just pad the smaller kernels with 0's and feed them to a "normal" convolution function.